# Opening a record based on a hyperlink - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have a report that displays a list of incident numbers (labeled LIN) and they show as hyperlinks. I want to build a macro where the user clicks the hyperlink and a form opens to that specific record (the LIN or incident number is a primary key). I can build the macro to open the correct form but can't figure out how to make it move to the corresponding record.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `FindRecord` macro.

Comment: I tried this but where it asks for what record to find, I cannot figure out how to search for the record based on what number is displayed on the report, i.e. say the incident number on the report is 23655 then once the user clicks on it, it should bring up record 23655 in the Edit Record Form. But somehow I just can't get it to do this. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Show me what you are using for each of the `FindRecord` arguments

Comment: FindRecord

   Find What - Reports![SOEID]![LIN]
   Match - Whole Field
   Match Case - No
   Search - All
   Search as Formatted - No
   Only Current Field - Yes
   Find First - Yes